# How to write list of integer to file for load in other time?

Tags: c#, string, file, io

I'm novice at c#, so it may little bit silly.

I want to write list of integer or array of integer to file.

If I use C, I may write down as following.

**For Saving**

```
int a[1024] = {0,};
fwrite(a,sizeof(int),1024,fp);
```

**For Loading**

```
int *a = null;
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

int ArraySize = ftell(fp)/sizeof(int);

a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*ArraySize);
fread(a,sizeof(int),1024,fp);
```

Is there any good way to saving and loading?

**Following is my c# code.**

**Saving**

```
List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>>();
...
...
StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(path);
foreach(List<int> i in a)
{
    wt.WriteLine(string.Join(",",i));
}
```

**Loading**

```
List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>>();
...
...
StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(path);
string s = "";
while((s=rd.ReadLine())!=null)
{
    a.add(s.split(',').select(int.Parse).toList());
}
```

If you guys have any idea, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the File Methods [`WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) and [`ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8), and some linq

```
// writing
var a = new List<List<int>>();
File.WriteAllLines("filename", a.Select(x => string.Join(",", x)));

// reading , you will need to read each line, split, then parse
var result = File.ReadLines("filename")
                 .Select(x => x.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

if you want to do this without parsing and splitting (in a more efficient manner), you can store the list in *binary* file

```
var list = new List<List<int>>();

using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("FileName", FileMode.Create)))
{
   foreach (var inner in list)
   {
      writer.Write(inner.Count);
      foreach (var item in inner)
         writer.Write(item);
   }
}

var results = new List<List<int>>();

using (var reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("FileName", FileMode.Open)))
{
   while(reader.BaseStream.Position < reader.BaseStream.Length)
   {
      var size = reader.ReadInt32();

      var inner = new List<int>(size);
      results.Add(inner);
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         inner.Add(reader.ReadInt32());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could make use of [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) and [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8). For example,

Write to File

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath,list.Select(x=>x.ToString()));
```

Read From File

```
var readList = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

The [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) projects each element of the sequence (in this case, all lines read from the text file) to Integers using the [`Convert.ToInt32'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is there any method to saving without conversion(string to integer or integer to string)? because I think that conversion is very slow and I have to process so many list(over 1 billion...)

Comment: @Teddy If you writing to Text File, it would be treated as String. The other alternative would be write to the contends as a Json Serialized array of integers and deserialize them as a whole when you read back